# How to upload and download a directory along with sub directory using spring integration with sftp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I need to know how to upload a directory to remote server and download a directory from remote server using sftp-spring boot with spring integration.

I can upload and download the file . but I cannot able to upload a folder (entire directory) . I want to upload entire directory which has sub directory also and the same for download thing.

This is my code for download a file from remote server.

```
 @Bean
 public DefaultSftpSessionFactory getSftpSessionFactory()
{
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory=new 
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setHost("hostName");
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPort(22);
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setUser("root");
    defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPassword("12qwaszx");
    return defaultSftpSessionFactory;
}

@Bean(name="mydefaultSync")
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer()
{
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer=new 
   SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(getSftpSessionFactory());
    synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/root/upload/");
    synchronizer.setFilter(new 
    SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
    return synchronizer;

}

@Bean(name="stfpServer")
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel="fileDownload", 
 poller=@Poller(fixedDelay = "3000"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSources()
{
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source=new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(synchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("download/"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
    return source;
}
```

It works for download a file from remote server. but  I need to download a directory along with sub directory from remote server using spring integration.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageSource` impls for remote files don't support recursive fetching yet: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3407.

However you can use an `SftpOutboundGateway` with its `MGET` (or `LS`) command support and `RECURSIVE` option.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#using-the-ls-command

Comment: There is also `MPUT`.

Answer (score -1):

if you know this directory, for example "/home/user/myFiles/image.png"
if you don't know the path you can split directories via "/" like that inputDirectory.split("/") and work with the list of directories

use these methods in ChannelSftp class:

1. cd("/") method to access road directory
2. mkdir("folderName") to create a new folder (surround it with try and catch because it will give an exception if the folder already exists)
3. put(InputStream src, String fileName, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, int mode) to upload the file
4. get(fileName) to download the file

and read this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-sftp

Comment: doesn't has anything to do with the question. It do not provide a viable way to download a folder with content